# OpenNHRP configuration without IPsec

Tags: linux, networking, cisco, dynamic, gre

I'm attempting to use OpenNHRP on a linux box to connect with a Cisco Router.

I want to allow GRE tunnels from the linux box to the Cisco router dynamically, but I'm not implementing DMVPN on the Cisco router.

I keep receiving the [Peer up script failed Exit Status: 1] error from OpenNHRP, which I've learned is due to no SA being negotiated.

I don't think I need an SA since I'm doing these GRE tunnels in the clear, and wondering whether anyone knew a way around this, or another way to do NHRP peers from a linux box.

/etc/opennhrp.conf

```
interface gre1
  map 10.10.10.1/24 172.17.6.2 register cisco
```

Cisco Router

```
interface tunnel10
ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
no ip redirects
ip mtu 1400
ip nhrp map multicast
ip nhrp network-id 2
tunnel source 172.17.6.2
tunnel mode gre multipoint
```

My GRE tunnels work fine when I statically assign endpoints to the GRE tunnels, but I need them to be dynamic for this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

edit the script /etc/opennhrp/opennhrp-script

comment below lines:

```
#racoonctl establish-sa -w isakmp inet $NHRP_SRCNBMA $NHRP_DESTNBMA || exit 1
#racoonctl establish-sa -w esp inet $NHRP_SRCNBMA $NHRP_DESTNBMA gre || exit 1 
#if [ "$NHRP_PEER_DOWN_REASON" != "lower-down" ]; then
        #racoonctl delete-sa isakmp inet $NHRP_SRCNBMA $NHRP_DESTNBMA
#fi
```

finally like this:
[opennhrp-script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owfFC.png)